# html positioning difficulty

Tags: html, css

[image]

How do I get the About Me and Education sections to the right side of the web

Here is pencode link: https://codepen.io/Weng-Hong-the-selector/pen/GRGjVLy

Here is my HTML and CSS
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>

  <div class="resume">
    <div class="resume_left">
      <div class="resume_profile">
        <img src="me.png" width=500px height=250px alt="profile_pic">
      </div>
      <div class="resume_content">
        <div class="resume_item resume_info">
          <div class="title">
            <p class="bold">TAN WENG HONG</p>
            <p class="regular">STUDENT OF DIPLOMA IN IT</p>
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="fas fa-mars-and-venus"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="data">
                Male
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-flag"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="data">
                Malaysian
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-signs-post"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="data">
                13A, Elitis Suria, Valencia, 47000, Sungai Buloh, Selangor
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="data">
                012-352-5089
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="data">
                wenghong.tan@sd.taylors.edu.my
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="resume_item resume_social">
          <div class="title">
            <p class="bold">Social</p>
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="data">
                <p><a href="https://www.facebook.com/tan.w.hong.16">Facebook</a></p>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="fab fa-instagram-square"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="data">
                <p><a href="https://www.instagram.com/wenghongggggg/">Instagram</a></p>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="data">
                <p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXdPTNsToFxqfBvHg_z5XTA">Youtube</a></p>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="data">
                <p><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/tan-weng-hong-314211251/">LinkedIn</a></p>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="resume_right">
          <div class="resume_item resume_about">
            <div class="title">
              <p class="bold">About me</p>
            </div>
            <p>My name is Tan Weng Hong and I am currently 19 years old</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="resume_item resume_education">
        <div class="title">
          <p class="bold">Education</p>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="date">2021 - present</div>
            <div class="info">
              <p class="semi-bold">Taylor's College</p>
              <p>Diploma in Information Technology</p>
              <p>Current CGPA: 3.01</p>
              <p>Will Graduate August 2023</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="date">2016 - 2020</div>
            <div class="info">
              <p class="semi-bold">SMK Sri KDU</p>
              <p>- Sijil Pelajaran Malaysia (SPM)</p>
              <p> &nbsp&nbspResults: 1A+ 1A 1C+ 1C 2D 3E 1G</p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="resume_item resume_hobby">
</body>

</html>
```

`

`

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #D3D3D3;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #555555;
  width: 200vh;
  text-align: center;
}

img{
  border: solid;
  border_width: 5px;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.semi-bold {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.regular{
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.resume {
  width: 1200px;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.resume .resume_left {
  width: 290px;
  height: 1050px;
  background: #0bb5f4;
  padding: 3px;
}

.resume .resume_left .resume_profile {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}

.resume .resume_left .resume_profile img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.resume .resume_left .resume_content {
  padding: 0 25px;
}

.resume .title {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.resume .resume_left .bold {
  color: #fff;
}

.resume .resume_left .regular {
  color: #b1eaff;
}

.resume .resume_item {
  padding: 25px 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #b1eaff;
}

.resume .resume_left ul li {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  align-items: center;
}

.resume .resume_left ul li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.resume .resume_left ul li .icon {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #0bb5f4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
}

.resume .icon i,
.resume ul li i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.resume .resume_left ul li .data {
  color: #b1eaff;
}

.resume .resume_left .resume_social .semi-bold {
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

`

i want my about me section and education section to be on the right side of info section, any idea how to get that to work? thank you in advance

Comment: text-align:right on .info? Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you already figured this out, but a quick look at your code I saw that you had a html organization problem so the ***resume_right*** was inside the ***resume_left***

this is your fixed code, hope it helps.

If after this you have any positioning problems, I suggest you read the **CSS flex** documentation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

```
<div class="resume">
    <div class="resume_left">
      <div class="resume_profile">
        <img src="me.png" width=500px height=250px alt="profile_pic">
      </div>
      <div class="resume_content">
        <div class="resume_item resume_info">
          <div class="title">
            <p class="bold">TAN WENG HONG</p>
            <p class="regular">STUDENT OF DIPLOMA IN IT</p>
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="fas fa-mars-and-venus"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="data">
                Male
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-flag"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="data">
                Malaysian
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-signs-post"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="data">
                13A, Elitis Suria, Valencia, 47000, Sungai Buloh, Selangor
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="data">
                012-352-5089
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="data">
                wenghong.tan@sd.taylors.edu.my
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="resume_item resume_social">
          <div class="title">
            <p class="bold">Social</p>
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="data">
                <p><a href="https://www.facebook.com/tan.w.hong.16">Facebook</a></p>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="fab fa-instagram-square"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="data">
                <p><a href="https://www.instagram.com/wenghongggggg/">Instagram</a></p>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="data">
                <p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXdPTNsToFxqfBvHg_z5XTA">Youtube</a></p>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="data">
                <p><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/tan-weng-hong-314211251/">LinkedIn</a></p>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
       
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="resume_right">
          <div class="resume_item resume_about">
            <div class="title">
              <p class="bold">About me</p>
            </div>
            <p>My name is Tan Weng Hong and I am currently 19 years old</p>
          </div>
           <div class="resume_item resume_education">
        <div class="title">
          <p class="bold">Education</p>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="date">2021 - present</div>
            <div class="info">
              <p class="semi-bold">Taylor's College</p>
              <p>Diploma in Information Technology</p>
              <p>Current CGPA: 3.01</p>
              <p>Will Graduate August 2023</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="date">2016 - 2020</div>
            <div class="info">
              <p class="semi-bold">SMK Sri KDU</p>
              <p>- Sijil Pelajaran Malaysia (SPM)</p>
              <p> &nbsp&nbspResults: 1A+ 1A 1C+ 1C 2D 3E 1G</p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use position to choose the place of your elements in the flow,
in your example, if you want to have your "About me" and "education" always displayed on the right of your screen you have to use

```
position : fixed;
right : 0;
```

If you want them to be scrolled like everything else, you can considere using

```
position : absolute;
right : 0;
```

In both case you'll have to be carefull of element stacking.
Here are informations about position :
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `text-align: right`, or `display: flex` together with `justify-content: flex-end`. In general, `text-align` works mostly on text elements, and `justify-content` will justify all elements and content.

Answer (score 0):

I think using flex box it will help you:

```
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end
```

or you can use positioning for this for example:

```
<div style = "position:absolute; left:80px; top:20px; background-color:yellow;">
     This div has absolute positioning.
</div>
```